# Google Maps API custom marker animation and orientation along path

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am trying to create a Google Map app that shows a route from a source to a destination in a straight line ('as the crow flies').
I have the general app working.
I can put in a start and an end destination and it will slowly draw a line from start to finish.
Also, I have a generic marker that moves along the straight line route from start to finish.
What I want to do is replace the generic marker with a custom drawn marker.  Also, I would like the custom marker to be oriented so that it is in line with the route.
In other words if the custom marker is a car I would want the car to be facing the right direction as it goes along the route.

I see this demo, but I am not sure how they are doing this.
http://www.morethanamap.com/demos/visualization/flights

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set a [IconSequence](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#add_to_polyline)  for the polyline. An IconSequence requires a Symbol, an example-SVG for a car : https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Car.svg
(©[Pypaertv](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Pypaertv))

Demo:

```js
function initialize() {


  var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(39.904211, 116.407394),
    destination = new google.maps.LatLng(40.4167754, -3.703790),
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: origin,
      zoom: 3
    }),
    line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      geodesic: true,
      path: [origin, origin],
      icons: [{
        icon: {
          path: 'M 236.54427,9.8485 C 220.2445,9.8485 204.45277,15.405415 191.41289,25.550223 L 97.337229,97.995127 L -135.0706,131.12201 C -150.90459,133.65817 -161.13586,149.44963 -156.32358,165.14237 L -132.57022,244.60846 L -86.188678,244.60846 C -90.823109,289.62242 -60.00389,319.2235 -20.679452,319.2235 C 18.644986,319.2235 49.844083,285.73585 44.829779,244.60846 L 425.19586,244.60846 C 419.65783,289.49008 452.23789,319.2235 490.70508,319.2235 C 529.17227,319.2235 561.22444,285.70267 556.21433,244.60846 L 651.04018,244.60846 C 659.88863,244.60846 667.48002,236.98237 667.48,227.63005 L 667.48,137.76012 C 667.48,129.20037 661.30023,122.08284 653.22799,120.97335 L 491.76774,97.995127 L 427.82125,32.635149 C 413.84999,18.051989 394.74442,10.165524 374.56372,9.8485 L 236.54427,9.8485 z M 304.42883,37.42226 L 378.62679,37.42226 C 389.64854,37.42226 399.73373,43.261111 405.94316,52.613356 L 424.25825,80.825395 C 428.78955,88.722668 423.85522,96.409133 415.38198,97.803717 L 304.42883,97.803717 L 304.42883,37.42226 z M 224.60508,37.549916 L 283.42586,37.549916 L 283.42586,97.803717 L 132.59212,97.803717 L 200.10167,45.97523 C 207.08728,40.585799 215.91189,37.549914 224.60508,37.549916 z',
          scale: .05,
          fillColor: 'blue',
          fillOpacity: 1,
          rotation: 90,
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 200)
        },

        offset: '100%'
      }]
    }),

    pct = 0,
    timer = setInterval(function() {

      pct += .002;

      line.setPath([origin, google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(origin, destination, pct)]);
      line.setMap(map);
      map.setCenter(line.getPath().getAt(1));
      if (pct >= 1) clearInterval(timer)
    }, 50);




}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Comment: This is great. What if I want to follow a route, should I iterate over the latitudes and longitudes and call setInterval in the for loop?

Comment: I also need that right at this moment, to animate a symbol following a route I found between two points. Did you find how to do it?